# How To Center Image Within Bootstrap Column

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I have several images within bootstrap columns like this:

```
<div class="services">
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 services-section">
                <img src="/images/website_design_icon.png"/>
                    <div class="services-paragraph">
                    <h3>Website Design</h3>
                    <p>WordPress themes built for design and functionality</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 services-section">
                <img src="/images/graphic_design_icon.png"/>
                    <div class="services-paragraph">
                    <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
                    <p>Logo designs for identity and print</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 services-section">
                <img src="/images/search_engine_marketing_icon.png"/>
                    <div class="services-paragraph">
                    <h3>Search Engine Marketing</h3>
                    <p>SEO strategies and PPC solutions to increase your presence online</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 services-section">
                <img src="/images/wordpress_conversion_icon.png"/>
                    <div class="services-paragraph">
                    <h3>WordPress Conversion</h3>
                    <p>Take advantage of the number-one CMS in Web Design to liberate your business</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div><!--/Row-->
    </div><!--/Container-->
    </div><!--/Services-->
```

As you can see each column has also been given a class of `services-section`. I've styled `.services-section img` in the CSS like this:

CSS:

```
.services-section img {
text-align: center;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
}
```

And I've tried adding various styles to this class - `float:none;`, `margin:auto;`, `vertical-align:middle;` - none of them have had any effect. I also tried giving the image a class - `.middle` and doing

```
.middle {
text-align: center;
}
```

In the CSS but that also had no effect.

I don't want to use `margin-left: 30px;` but I don't know how else to push the images towards the center of their columns. Thanks for any other suggestions, the site is live here:

http://nowordpress.gatewaywebdesign.com/

Comment: set text-align on .services-section only

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add  `display: block` and `margin: auto;` it will do the trick

```
.services-section img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;    
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This also works and this way I don't have to get rid of `img` from `.services-section img` - thank you.

Comment: @HappyHands31 Your Welcome :)

Comment: You can also put `class="d-block m-auto"` on your img tag.

Comment: This is actually documented, at least in v5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/images/#aligning-images using the helper clases d-block for display: block and mx-auto for margin auto (left and right)

Answer (score 1):

set text-align on .services-section only like so:

```
.services-section {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[CodePen Example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWBrMG)